# Calculations based on different dates in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[K_FS_GetBalanceforOrderconfirm]
@name varchar(50),
@date datetime
as
begin

select round(sum(DISTINCT AR.recamount) - sum(OD1.noofbags*MR.rateperkg*BG.bagtype),2)   as balance from K_FS_AmountReceived AR inner join K_FS_OrderDetails1 OD1 on AR.orderno =OD1.ID 
inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on BG.sno = OD1.bagtype
inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT on FT.sno = OD1.feedtype
inner join K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MR on FT.sno=MR.feedtype 
where AR.Name = @name and MR.date = @date

end
```

Above query gives output  based on date, but sum(.......) some values already have some date including that date sum(....) I want sum(......) based on whatever value been passed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in not clear to me. Are you trying to say that some tables are already have daily value summarized?

From my experience I would suggest to start with preparing data with intermediate subqueries. Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM (SELECT * FROM RawData WHERE RowData.col1_date = @mydate) a
```

This way you can run subqueries independently and see what you get there.

Comment: In above mensioned tables different rows with different dates.What actually i want is sum of cloumn values based on that rows date wise

Comment: I think you need to prepare your data first in subquery and then filter only relevant date. This will run a bit slower, but this way it will be easier for you to deal with data. Another approach is to add "AND data = @mydate" on each JOIN

Comment: how to write subquery show me example of above if you don't mind

Comment: Please see the example I provided in my answer